# Android creates radius for rounded corners for smaller shapes only at left

Tags: android, android-drawable, layer-list, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I set `android:radius="20dp"` but why rounded corners only at the left? Red shape should also have rounded corners at the right as well

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#c61b1f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="20dp"/>
            <padding android:left="60dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#eeeeee" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

**Updated**

I want to achieve the next background for `EditText`

[image]

We can set `width` for `item` (for first left shape) but it's only available from 23+ API, I need to support 21+

I have a solution for 23+ API:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item> 
    // white shape
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#eeeeee" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item> 
    // red shape
    <item android:width="60dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#c61b1f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: red right corners are behind the white bro.

Comment: remove white and check again

Comment: make separate drawable for red add width then add in this item.

Comment: 2nd opt - add padding to the red from right

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, the right side also has a corner radius now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#eeeeee" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:right="340dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#c61b1f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It gives the following result

[image]

Comment: @user924 I have updated the answer as per your query

Comment: `340dp` seems not very good,  I can't know the width of white background, I can only have fixed size for red shape (for example 60dp). I tested this background with EditText and only white shape displayed

Comment: @user924 I feel like you would be better off then to the overlay over your EditText inside the XML layout. 
Since without assigning padding, from the right end, or without specifying a  width, the last item of layer list will always end up over the another. You can also use the right keyword, instead of padding which I feel is slightly better and I have updated the same.

Answer (score 0):

Invisible because of being covered.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#c61b1f" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <padding android:left="60dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#eeeeee" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: red shape should also have rounded corners at the right

Comment: Can you take a look at my renderings? Is that so?

Comment: I updated the question again, added an example solution which works for Android 23+ API